# Angular 4 ngFor set class for element

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I am new to Angular and I am trying to make side menu using material lists and ngFor.

```
<md-list-item
  *ngFor="let linkItem of linkItems"
  class="{{linkItem.className}}" 
  routerLink="{{linkItem.routerLink}}"
  (click)="listItemClickToggle(linkItem)">
  {{linkItem.linkName}}
</md-list-item >
```

everything works fine except setting `class`. IS there any different approach to do it?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { LinkItem } from './link-item';

const LINK_ITEMS: LinkItem[] = [
  {
    linkName: 'Weather',
    className: 'list-item',
    routerLink: '/weather'
  },
  {
    linkName: 'Top visits',
    className: 'list-item',
    routerLink: '/visits'
  },
  {
    linkName: 'Photo Gallery',
    className: 'list-item',
    routerLink: '/gallery'
  }
]

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})



export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'My forum';

  linkItems: LinkItem[] = LINK_ITEMS;
  selectedListItem: LinkItem;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedListItem = null;
  }

  listItemClickToggle(linkItem: LinkItem): void {
    console.log(linkItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you inspect in developer tools ? Do you see `class=""` or no class attribute is added to `<md-list-item></md-list-item>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `[ngClass]` instead of just class

```
[ngClass]="linkItem.className"
```